# Let $f(x,y)$ be polynomial, and it has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, and irreducible.Can we say that the tangent fails to exist?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be polynomial, and it has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, and irreducible.

Can we say that  the tangent fails to exist ?

Comment: perhaps you could assist by specifying where the tangent fails to exist...

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true?